# SML function parameters: tuple, currying, type synonyms

Tags: types, sml, currying

I start with this

```
type int_pair = int * int
```

and then have these

```
fun sip1 ((i,j) : int_pair) = (j,i)
fun sip1a (ip : int_pair) = (#2 ip, #1 ip)
fun sip2 (ip : int*int) = (#2 ip, #1 ip)
fun sip3 (i : int, j : int) = (j,i)
```

with these results

```
: val sip1 = fn : int_pair -> int * int
: val sip1a = fn : int_pair -> int * int
: val sip2 = fn : int * int -> int * int
: val sip3 = fn : int * int -> int * int
```

They all work. What puzzles me is how the `sip1` and `sip1a` can be set up to take a single `int_pair` variable `ip` or as tuple-like `(i,j)`. How can it handle both just due to the type synonym? I simply assume that any sort of `(a,b)` in the body will default to type `int*int` on return, but also, in the expression `(j,i)` of `sip1` it seems to not need the referencing (`#1`...) of `sip1a`. Rather peculiar at first glance. `sip2` seems straight-on. But then in `sip3` it would seem to be simply two `int`s going in and a result of type `int*int` coming out; but the function type says it is `int * int -> int * int`. Why is it not type `int -> int -> int*int` as I might have seen in other languages? IOW, why does ML treat multiple incoming variables as a tuple?

Comment: The argument `(i, j)` is not "tuple-like", it *is* a tuple. All functions take exactly one argument.

Comment: See also `fun sip4 ((i,j) : int * int)`, and `fun sip5 ((i : int, j : int) : int*int)` and `fun sip6 ((i : int, j : int) : int_pair)`

Comment: All your functions have the same type, it's just that when you specifically use your type synonym, so does the interpreter - if you enter `fun sip7 (ip: int * int) = ip : int_pair;`, you're greeted with `val sip7 = fn : int * int -> int_pair`.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that statement "All functions take exactly one argument," but not known what to make of it, since I see functions with multiple incoming variables. So technically `fun sip3 (i : int, j : int) = (j,i)` is not getting two variables, but one packaged as a tuple. So why are clearly two incoming dependent variables considered just one? What is the computer science theory behind this? -- my original question could be worded as. Is this something from the lambda calculus world? I've seen ML tutorials that start you out with lambda calculus. . . .

Comment: `sip1` and `sip3` use *pattern matching*. Pattern-matching is able to unpack the tuple, binding the items to `i` and `j` (in this case). That SML function definitions are able to use pattern matching doesn't imply that the functions so defined are functions of more that 1 variable.

Comment: Start at page 28 in Paulson.

Comment: p. 30 - "Strictly speaking, every ML function has one argument and one result." Why? Again, with `sip3` in any other language there are two incoming variables. ML, however, merges them into one tuple. What is the reason, advantage to doing this?

Comment: Tuples ARE the computer science theory behind n-ary functions. But many languages make arbitrary distinctions between tuples occurring as parameter lists and other uses of tuples. One advantage of avoiding such bifurcation is that functions are more composable, e.g., you can write `sip3 (sip2 p)` in SML, or in fact, `sip3 o sip2`, where `o` is the function composition operator.

Comment: @Andreas Rossberg: This is what I was wondering. If you know any further literature on this aspect, let me know. I've been around programming for a while and have never heard of this before. So, yes, if anyone knows of a good treatment of this, let me know. I doubt many Java, C#, Python etc. programmers have ever seen this. And this is not to be confused with some sort of lambda calculus lore?

Comment: Well, lambda calculus is the foundation of the scientific theory of programming languages and their semantics -- which surely most programmers do not know much about (as they are practitioners). An excellent introduction into programming language theory would be Benjamin Pierce's text book "Types and Programming Languages".

Comment: I'm still trying to get at the Kern of this "one variable only" issue. Again, after many years in programming, this is totally new to me. (Here's a C function with variable parameters: ` double average(int num,...)` ). But I sense it is necessary for bigger things like tupling and currying and partial application, etc. . . . Or it's just something peculiar to the ML parser? Again, I never noticed this, but literally any multiple parameter function in ML considers the parameters of type n-tuple. I can't be the only person that finds this amazing/bizarre.

Comment: @147pm, it simplifies the language by unifying some concepts (orthogonality), which also happens to make the language more composable. That's the whole answer, not sure what else you're looking for. Other functional languages tend to make similar decisions (though usually preferring curried to cartesian). The reason why mainstream langs don't is that they tend to be more low-level and more driven by implementation concerns than semantic uniformity (and traditionally don't have a notion of tuple or closure to begin with).

Comment: Curious: What do you mean by "orthogonality" in this context? I know it from linear algebra only. And what do you mean by ". . .though usually preferring curried to cartesian"? I have a rough grasp of what currying is, but how are you contrasting it to cartesian? I really crave an understanding of the theoretical underpinnings. Once I get a sufficient understanding of all these issue, factors, I'll write up an "Answer Your Question."

Comment: Orthogonality describes the property that each feature of a formal system provides expressiveness along an independent "dimension", i.e., is not redundant and can be combined with all other features. For programming languages, this term came into use with the [design of Algol 68](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/en.post.algol-68-revised-report.html#012).

Comment: Cartesian in the sense of using tuples (i.e., product types). Multi-parameter functions can be represented with either curried parameters (e.g., as functions of type `T -> U -> V`) or with tuple parameter (e.g., as functions of type `T * U -> V`). Most modern functional languages prefer the former, while SML remains a bit more traditional in preferring the latter most of the times. Though thanks to pattern matching, it is equally possible to use either (`fun f x y = e` vs `fun f (x, y) = e`) or even mix them (`fun f (x, y) (v, w) = e`).

Answer (score 1):

In ML all functions take exactly one argument. But when we need to send more than one argument, ML interprets the arguments in the traditional parentheses as a single *tuple*, in keeping with the one argument only rule:

```
fun swap1 (i,j) = (j,i)
: val swap1 = fn : 'a * 'b -> 'b * 'a
```

The two arguments above separated by the `*` means they are a 2-arity tuple.

```
- swap1 (1,2);
val it = (2,1) : int * int
```

Even when variables seem separate, they are still considered a single argument, again, a 2-arity tuple:

```
fun swap1a (i : int, j : int) = (j,i)
: val swap1 = fn : int * int -> int * int
```

If we create a type synonym with `type`, e.g.,

```
type int_pair = int * int
```

functions using `int_pair` still are typed as tuples:

```
fun swap2 ((i,j) : int_pair) = (j,i)
: val swap2 = fn : int_pair -> int * int
fun swap2a (ip : int_pair) = (#2 ip, #1 ip)
: val swap2a = fn : int_pair -> int * int
fun swap2b (ip : int*int) = (#2 ip, #1 ip)
: val swap2b = fn : int * int -> int * int
```

ML also has *curried* functions where multiple arguments are *curried*, basically meaning the arguments are taken in one at a time, which, again, holds to the only-one-argument rule. Currying allows us to *partially apply* a function to some of its arguments, leaving a residual function which can be further evaluated later. The special ML syntax for a function that employs currying is to simply have the arguments without enclosing parentheses and separated by a space:

```
fun swap3 i j = (j,i)
: val swap3 = fn : 'a -> 'b -> 'b * 'a

- swap3 1 2;
val it = (2,1) : int * int
```

Another visualization is to construct `swap3` with anonymous functions:

```
- val swap3a = fn i => fn j => (j,i)
- swap3a 1 2;
val it = (2,1) : int * int
```

Now, we might envision the incoming `1 2` being resolved right-to-left (ironically called *left-associating*) *a la* lambda calculus:

```
(fn i => fn j => (j,i))(1,2)
(fn i => (2,i))(1)
(2,1)
```

Notice that `fn i =>...` is actually *accepting a function as its input*, in this example, the anonymous function expression `fn j =>...`, which has the value `(2,i)`. In fact, the spirit of this can be done at the REPL:

```
- ((fn i => fn j => (j,i)) 1) 2;
val it = (2,1) : int * int
```

As commenter Andreas Rossberg says (see above comments), in most functional languages, multiple argument functions employ currying. He notes that the use of tuples is *cartesian* in the sense of a cartesian product. He also notes that this is *orthogonal*, which in this context might mean that these two approaches to handling multiple arguments, tuple and currying, are *orthogonal* to each other in that they're completely opposite, non-overlapping approaches that don't semantically interfere with one another.

Comment: A couple of remarks: (1) my comment regarding orthogonality was about not introducing both tuples and n-ary functions as redundant concepts; (2) the absence or presence of parentheses is irrelevant, `fun f (x) (y) = ...` is a curried function, too; (3) all parameters are written as *patterns* and type annotations have no operational effect in patterns, so `(x,y)`, `(x : int, y)`, `((x,y) : int * int)`, `((((x) : int, ((y))) : int_pair))` are all equivalent patterns modulo type checking; (4) `fn j => ...` in your example is not an input, it's the *result* of the outer function.

Comment: Yes, I'll investigate further what orthogonality means. Thanks for the other corrections, too. All too often I see "hand-waving" at these issues. Yes, `fun f x y = . . .` is the same as `fun f (x) (y) . . .` but my source for that info did not mention that fact, rather, made it seem like without parentheses was the one and only syntax. I'm trying to design a curriculum for secondary education, and I need to remove all such hand-waving. IOW, verbosity is not a problem.